Is there a way to convert days from the datetime import into an integer
I am fairly new to programming and to practice I decided to make a program to calculate how many days you have been alive and then convert that into how many hours you have been alive. However, I have no idea how to convert the days into an integer to stop it from printing " days, 0:00:00" after the amount of days and hours.
Here's the code I have:
from datetime import date
    
today = date.today()
day = input("Please enter the day you were born on:\n")
month = input("Please enter the month you were born in:\n")
year = input("Please enter the year you were born in:\n")
birthdate = date(int(year), int(month), int(day))
    
days = today - birthdate
hours = days * 24
    
print(days)
print(hours)


Use days = (today - birthdate).days
